TexWorks compiling not working
i just installed Texworks and MiKTex on my Computer. I already use it on my Laptop for Uni but wanted to also have it on my PC so I can also access and edit my files from there. However, when I try compiling my Files, i get a message that PDFLatex is not properly configured, and I also can't choose Typesets that I can access on my laptop (e.g. combinations like pdfLatex+ BibTex + MakeIndex) aren't listed and all listed Typesets are greyed out. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Welcome to TeX.SE. Clearly, something hasn't gone according to plan. It would help a lot if you edited your query to copy and paste the actual error and warning messages you've been receiving. Without these, it's not really possible to provide a diagnosis, let alone suggest a cure.
